# Azure DevOps Server 2019 を Azure CLI で操作する

Tags: azure

Azure DevOps Server 2019に対してAzure CLIを用いてアクセスしたいです。
ですが、[Microsoft Docs:Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)には

> The Azure DevOps Command Line Interface (CLI) is available for Azure DevOps Server 2020 and Azure DevOps Services.

と記載があります。
ではDevOps 2019を使用している方々はどのようにコマンドラインから操作しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

似たようなことを考えている方がいました。
[[Bug] vsts-cli tool does not work with (onprem) Azure DevOps Server 2019 SP1.1; *self-signed* certificate #323](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/323)

そこで、[Microsoft Docs:Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)に従い、試してみたところ上手くいきました。

> To start using the Azure DevOps extension for Azure CLI, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Install Azure CLI:
> 2. Add the Azure DevOps extension:
> 3. Sign in:

---

サインインは以下で試してみたところ上手くいきました。
トークンはMS Docsにある通り作成できます。

```
$az devops login --organization http://FooBar:8080/tfs/FooBarCollection
Token:xxxxxxx
```

その後適当なコマンド`az pipelins list -p FooBarProject`を実行するとそれらしい結果が表示できたので、
オンプレ版のAzure DevOps Server 2019でもAzure CLIが使用できると判断しました。